# Block key presses for a certain amount of time (Java Game Development)

Tags: java, keylistener, key-bindings

I'm building a 2D game from scratch for educational purposes. For now, a character should move on tiles. If, say, the left arrow is pressed, I want the character to move left an entire tile and then stop. In the meantime, it should ignore all other key presses, including up, down and right. So far, I handled this with a keyListener and a TimerTask which would check if the key is still pressed after the time had elapsed and then make the character stop moving. I noticed however, that the keyPressed event was constantly triggered, generating more and more TimerTasks, which resulted ultimately in delayed input reactions. This is what I did, when a key was pressed:

```
private void moveLeft() {
    if (map.getNextTile("Left").isPassable()){
        if (moving.equals("")){
            moving = "Left";
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (keyStillPressed[0] == false) {
                        xSpeed = 0;
                        moving = "";
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                    } else {
                        if (map.getNextTile("Left").isPassable()){
                            xSpeed = 1;
                            map.movePlayerLeft();
                        } else {
                            xSpeed = 0;
                            moving = "";
                            timer.cancel();
                            timer.purge();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 320);
        }
    }
    setFacing("Left");
}
```

I first check if the next tile is terrain that is passable. If yes, I check if the character is currently moving. If no, then I start the timer and its task. keyStillPressed is an array that tells me, if the corresponding key is still pressed. Say it still is pressed, and it is true: I once again check if the next tile is passable (had some issues where keeping the key pressed allowed me to move through walls, and this fixed it), and if yes, I set the speed to 1, which moves the map to the right (and essentially, the character to the left).

map.movePlayerLeft() lets the map know, where the player currently is located so as to trigger events when stepping on something. If the next tile is not passable, the character gets stopped, I reset moving to an empty String and cancel the timer. Since every tile is 32 pixels and I move 1 pixel every 10 milliseconds, the looping time is 320 milliseconds.

Now, I know handling the state of the player via a String is not cool and all. And obviously using keyListener is crap, so I decided to use keyBindings. That sadly doesnt help me for my task of blocking all keyinputs while the character is moving sadly.

Is using a timer to trespass an entire tile-distance even correct? How can I get the game to not listen to all other key inputs during the time the character is moving?

**EDIT**

Okay I failed to specify the problem. I modified the code as childofsoong suggested:

```
private void moveLeft() {
    if (!occupied){
        if (map.getNextTile("Left").isPassable()){
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (!occupied) {
                        xSpeed = 1;
                        map.movePlayerLeft();
                        occupied = true;
                    } else {
                        xSpeed = 0;
                        occupied = false;
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer.purge();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 320);
        }
        setFacing("Left");
    }
}
```

That should simplify things. What problem I'm left with now is that if I started pressing a different button while moving in one direction, and keeping it presse, once I'm finished moving there's a short delay of 0.2 to 0.5 seconds before I'll start moving in a different direction.

I don't want to queue actions, I just don't want that delay, and I don't understand where it stems from.

Comment: Why not just use a boolean flag to determine if you can move on each key press, which you toggle when you start/stop moving?

Comment: That's so easy it could work. Hold on, I'll test it.

Comment: Kay, that made the code a lot more readable, but didn't resolve the issue I originally had (but smartly didn't specify.) Whenever I press, say, the right button while going up, and keep it pressed until I'm standing on the tile and even longer, what should be happening is immediately after landing on that tile, the character should go right. But there's a short delay of sometimes 0.2, sometimes 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Well you could write some code so that when the right button is pressed, it registers that you want to go right once any current move actions are complete, and then each move action could trigger checking for that and acting accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to queue inputs. Also, if I keep the up button pressed, after the first tile there's a short delay, which doesn't happen after the second and the third and so on.